# Spring/Java @DecimalMin inclusive doesn't work in VSCode (The attribute inclusive is undefined for the annotation type DecimalMin Java(67109475)

Tags: java, spring, visual-studio-code

[image]

as seen in the picture it shows me thet the inclusive attribute is undefined. Couldn't find anything on that, on examples it is shown exactly like my code. Code below:

```
   @NotNull
        @Digits(integer = 10, fraction = 2)
        @DecimalMin(value = "0.01", inclusive = false)
        private BigDecimal price;
```

i tried fixing it using google and java documentation, but there is kinda no workaround

Comment: Wrong dependency older or newer then the one used in the sample. Or the wrong `@DecimalMin` annotation.

Comment: Will the same environment and code work in the IDEA?

Comment: Yes it has worked in IDEA